# Dynamic Measure From Date Slicer Not working as expected

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have similar problem statement of ([PowerBI/DAX: Unable to correctly compare two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015681/powerbi-dax-unable-to-correctly-compare-two-dates/74726351?noredirect=1#comment131886431_74726351))

where I'm selected the start date and end date from slicer and wrote DAX for the measures as

Start_Date = CALCULATE(Min('Calendar'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('Calendar'))

End_Date = CALCULATE(Max('Calendar'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('Calendar'))

And I use them to compare with a column and return TRUE or FALSE.

IsTrue_Flag = IF(table[prod_date]>=[Start_Date] && table[prod_date] <= [End_Date], TRUE, FALSE)

But all my values are turning as TRUE which is not the case.

Where did I go wrong with the DAX? please help

Comment: "IsTrue_Flag looks like a calculated column, not a measure. Columns don't respond to slicers.

Comment: @RADO It should respond to measures as far as I know. I'm taking slicer value into a measure, and then measure is used in IF condition. I even tried hardcoding the measure value with Date() function and it was working as expected, but now I wanted to make it dynamic since I change the measure value on weekly basis and publish. So I want to explore how can I put a calendar slicer and the min and max dates are taken into measure and then used to calculate my flags.

Comment: If you created ""IsTrue_Flag" as a calculated column, then your approach won't work.

Comment: How do I approach this scenario ? I basically want to calculate number of TRUE's as total productions in a week. Please suggest if there' is a better approach

Comment: I understand in general what you are trying to do; your current approach won't work (See here why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148028/powerbi-calculatetable-filter-with-selectedvalue/70148616#70148616). To help more, I need to see your data model and an example of the desired outcome. A data sample would help too. I recommend to close this question and write a new one.