# How to compare Date column with a date measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to compare a date column with date measure whose value is taken from the Calendar slicer.

- DAX for Date measures

```
Week_Start_Date = CALCULATE(Min('Calendar'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('Calendar'))
```

```
Week_End_Date = CALCULATE(Max('Calendar'[Date]),ALLSELECTED('Calendar'))
```

- DAX for Calculated column

```
Submissions_Week_Flag = IF('Tracker'[Submitted Date].[Date] >= [Week_Start_Date] && 'Tracker'[Submitted Date].[Date] <= [Week_End_Date],1,0)
```

But all my flags are turned 1. How do I compare the dates in this scenario.
There is no relationship between the 'Calendar' table and 'Tracker' table.

Comment: You already asked this here: [Dynamic Measure From Date Slicer Not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74726438/dynamic-measure-from-date-slicer-not-working-as-expected). Please consider the comments!

Comment: Ok, what RADO was trying to tell you still holds. You cannot have a calculated column be responsive to a slicer, since a calculated column is calculated and set before any slicer selection is possible - when the model is loaded or refreshed.
You want a measure, not a calculated column since you need it to be reactive.
Please, restate your desired mechanics/logic in some general terms. What do you want this measure to do, and why?

Comment: Before I used to harcode my Week_Start_Date and Week_End_Date measure using Date() function. For example, 
Week_Start_Date = DATE(2022,11,27)
Week_End_Date = DATE(2022,12,03)

These measure are used in Calculated column as stated above (Submissions_Week_Flag), and I used to sum all the flags for weekly submissions. Since I have to change these measures on a weekly basis and re-publish it, I want to automate the change of dates in measures, so that I choose the dates from a calendar slicer and it gets fed into measures, and then get the flag results. Is there any other approach to this?

Comment: It is not possible to make a calculated column(Submissions_Week_Flag) based on the dynamic measures(Week_Start_Date and Week_End_Date). You should get other measures using the dynamic measures(Week_Start_Date and Week_End_Date), not the flag.

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into the same problem. When manually changing the measure "Week_Start_Date" or "Week_End_Date", this causes Power BI to recalculate associated fields, so the "Submissions_Week_Flag" gets updated.

When you switch to using the dynamic values in "Week_Start_Date" or "Week_End_Date", changing the filter changes the values in those measures, but it doesn't cause "Submissions_Week_Flag" to recalculate, so it is using whatever default value is stored in either measure.

As others suggested, the way around this is to create the flag as a measure instead of a calculated column.